# Playing video with VideoView causes MediaPlayer(1873): error (1, -2147483648)

Tags: android, android-camera

When I try and play a 3GP video with VideoView the following error occurs:

> MediaPlayer(1873): error (1, -2147483648)

My source code is:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

        /*
         * MediaController mc=new MediaController(VideoPlayer.this); mc.show(0);
         * mc.setEnabled(true); mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
         */

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent == null) {
            System.out.println("intent is null");
            return;
        }
        Util.showToast(R.string.play_video, VideoPlayer.this);
        String mUri = intent.getStringExtra("path");
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(mUri);
        mVideoView.start();
        System.out.println("path: " + mUri);

    }
```

The error information is:

```
    01-01 00:19:04.000: INFO/ActivityManager(1456): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.cameradiag/.VideoPlayer (has extras) } from pid 1873
01-01 00:19:04.015: VERBOSE/videocamera(1873): stopVideoRecording
01-01 00:19:04.015: VERBOSE/videocamera(1873): Releasing media recorder.
01-01 00:19:04.015: VERBOSE/videocamera(1873): closeCamera
01-01 00:19:04.015: ERROR/CameraHal(1387): hardware/ti/omap3/camera-omap4/src/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:248 disableMsgType - Message type 0x200 subscription no supported yet!
01-01 00:19:04.015: ERROR/OMXCameraAdapter(1387): hardware/ti/omap3/camera-omap4/src/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:3458 stopPreview - Average framerate: 25.296116
01-01 00:19:04.023: ERROR/CameraHal(1387): hardware/ti/omap3/camera-omap4/src/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:248 disableMsgType - Message type 0x200 subscription no supported yet!
01-01 00:19:04.023: INFO/TIOverlay(1456): Destroying overlay/fd=194/obj=45c97000
01-01 00:19:04.023: DEBUG/TIOverlay(1456): mZorderUsage[0] = 0 should be removed
01-01 00:19:04.023: ERROR/CameraHal(1387): hardware/ti/omap3/camera-omap4/src/AppCallbackNotifier.cpp:1473 stop - AppCallbackNotifier already in stopped state
01-01 00:19:04.195: WARN/ASFDummyExtractor(1387): ASF parser is not available
01-01 00:19:04.195: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(1387): setDataSource('/mnt/media/Video/VID_20000101_001843.3gp')
01-01 00:19:04.195: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(1387): setDataSource_l(/mnt/media/Video/VID_20000101_001843.3gp)
01-01 00:19:04.203: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1873): error (1, -2147483648)
01-01 00:19:04.257: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1873): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-01 00:19:04.257: DEBUG/VideoView(1873): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-01 00:19:04.296: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1873): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 852K, 54% free 2894K/6215K, external 1889K/2137K, paused 32ms
01-01 00:19:04.554: INFO/ActivityManager(1456): Displayed com.android.cameradiag/.VideoPlayer: +447ms
01-01 00:19:07.156: ERROR/Omap4ALSA(1387): called drain&close
01-01 00:19:09.429: ERROR/OMXCameraAdapter(1387): hardware/ti/omap3/camera-omap4/src/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:7229 Handler - Exiting command handler
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: From where you are getting your video path raw folder or sdcard?

Comment: @suri sahani the path is:/mnt/media/Video/VID_20000101_001843.3gp /mnt/media link to /mnt/sdcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found root cause: there is no permission for my application to access /mnt/media/Video/VID_20000101_001843.3gp.

Comment: Care to name the permission for the benefit of others?

Comment: @baggyrabbit sorry,what does you mean?

Comment: I meant, Was it just the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: @Judy what permission were you missiong?

Comment: @Fallenreaper I didn't miss any permission

Comment: @judy : How you can fix this issue? You did not update your answer for people understand?